# How can I hide errors in Evolution?

Tags: settings, evolution

I'm using a university email account that's apparently  badly configured, Evolution keeps sending me errors whenever I do something, all about "Unexpected server response".

I'm wondering, whether I can force-hide warnings based on unexpected server response? If not, just force-ignore all warnings/errors that Evolution sends?

Evolution was the only email/calendar solution for elementary OS I found after a long day that properly integrated google calendar delegates, so I'd rather not change email/calendar again.

Answer (score 1):

if they are bubble notification you can always turn them off in setting>notifications.